# Can someone explain why I am not getting the concatenated value of the 1st name,2nd name & "Developers"

Tags: python

Can someone explain why I am not getting the concatenated value of the 1st name,2nd name & "Developers",once I call the out() function after giving both the inputs there is no output

def out():

```
x=input("Please input 1st name: ")
y=input("Please input 2nd name: ")
def inn():
    return x+y


    def inn1():
        b=inn()+"developers"
        print(b)
    inn1()
inn()
```

Comment: Because the first statement in `inn` is `return`. And you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: It is difficult to tell, as the indentation is not good. please edit. It can also be that you never call    out() in your code, and inn1() may not be called also as it is hidden after a return statement.

Answer (score 2):

A working way to do it is:

- use arguments to pass x and y values to each function
- use indentation (not very clear in your question)
- I kept the 3 functions but one could be enough in your case (see at the end)

  ```
  def out():

    x=input("Please input 1st name: ")
    y=input("Please input 2nd name: ")

    def inn(x, y):
        return x+y


    def inn1(x, y):
        b=inn(x, y)+"developers"
        print(b)

    inn1(x, y)
  out()
  ```

Output is :

```
Please input 1st name: A

Please input 2nd name: B
ABdevelopers
```

A solution with only one function can be:

```
def inn(x, y):
    return x+y+"developers"

x=input("Please input 1st name: ")
y=input("Please input 2nd name: ")

print(inn(x, y))
```

You can even write it as a one liner, but it is less readable:

```
print(input("Please input 1st name: ")+input("Please input 2nd name: ")+"developers")
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have called `inn()` your program stops at the `return` block. Therefore, `inn1()` is never run.
Instead, try:

```html
def inn():
     b = x+y+" Developers"
     return b
inn()
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to use multiple nested functions to get the output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the result on the console then use in your last code:

```
print(inn())
```

and if you want to run the inner def you shouldn't put `return` in the parent def, put a variable instead,
try this code:

```
x=input("Please input 1st name: ")
y=input("Please input 2nd name: ")

def inn():
    re =  x+y

    def inn1():
        b = re +"developers"
        print(b)
    inn1()

print(inn())
```

Answer (score 0):

Code after return x+y is dead. It can't be reached

**Change your code to this**

```
x=input("Please input 1st name: ")
y=input("Please input 2nd name: ")
def inn():
    return x+y

def inn1():
    b=inn()+"developers"
    print(b)
inn1()
```